# Ember Data - Creating a new record with association requires hooking into promises?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to get my head around Ember Data by creating a simple attendance app. The goal is to have a student type in their name and hit submit, creating a new Attendance record that is associated with that student. Here's what I've done to make it work:

```
App.Student = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  attendances: DS.hasMany('attendance', { async: true })
});

App.Attendance = DS.Model.extend({
  student: DS.belongsTo('student', { async: true }),
  ...
});
```

--

```
App.NewAttendanceController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  content: {},
  actions: {
    createAttendance: function() {
      var studentName = this.get('name');
      this.store.find('student', { name: studentName })
      .then(function(fulfilledPromise) {
        var student = fulfilledPromise.get('firstObject');
        var attendance = fulfilledPromise.store.createRecord('attendance', {
          time: moment(),
          student: student
        });
        attendance.save();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

In the `createAttendance` action I first grab the inputted name, find matching `student` records, wait for the fulfilled promise before grabbing the first `student`, then create a new `attendance` record with it's student property set to the grabbed `student` record and save it.

So this works, but it feels really strange. I'm hoping someone could show me a better way to go about selecting records and making associations in Ember Data.

Comment: That's pretty much the workflow since you don't already have an instance of the student, or the student's id (for a find by id).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the response.